# Attempting to Call an Encryption Algorithm Generates NoSuchAlgorithmException

Tags: java, algorithm, encryption, cryptography, encryption-symmetric

When trying to compile the following code, I generate NoSuchAlgorithmException every time, regardless of what string I assign to the algorithm variable (AES, DESede, etc). The error is always thrown in the constructor, when I'm first trying to assign a value to the key, and for the life of me I can't manage to figure out what the issue is. I've included the entire file in the off chance that something is relevant, but the only problem area seems to be the constructor. If anyone is familiar with this issue and could point out where I'm going wrong, I'd be very grateful.

```
public class Seclib {


      private static String algorithm = "AES";
      private static Key key = null;
      private static Cipher cipher = null;

    public Seclib(){
        key = KeyGenerator.getInstance(algorithm).generateKey();
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
    }

    public static String messageHash(String message) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(message.getBytes());
        return md.digest(message.getBytes()).toString();
    }

    public static byte[] encryptMessage(String input) throws InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] inputBytes = input.getBytes();
        return cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);
    }   

    private static String decrypt(byte[] encryptionBytes) throws InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] recoveredBytes = 
        cipher.doFinal(encryptionBytes);
        String recovered = new String(recoveredBytes);
        return recovered;
    }   

    public static String initializeSecurityParameters(Scanner reader, int securityArray[]){

        int flagC = 0;
        int flagI = 0;
        int flagA = 0;

        String securityArrayString = "";

        String s;

        while(flagC == 0){

            System.out.println("Does this session require confidentiality? Y/N");
            System.out.println();
            s = reader.next();
            System.out.println();

            if(s.equals("Y") || s.equals("y") || s.equals("N") || s.equals("n")){

                if(s.equals("Y") || s.equals("y")){
                    securityArray[0] = 1;
                    flagC = 1;
                }else{
                    securityArray[0] = 0;
                    flagC = 2;
                }
            }

            if(flagC == 0){
                System.out.println("Invalid entry, must be one of Y,y,N,n");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        while(flagI == 0){

            System.out.println("Does this session require integrity? Y/N");
            System.out.println();
            s = reader.next();
            System.out.println();

            if(s.equals("Y") || s.equals("y") || s.equals("N") || s.equals("n")){
                flagI = 1;
                if(s.equals("Y") || s.equals("y")){
                    securityArray[1] = 1;
                    flagI = 1;
                }else{
                    securityArray[1] = 0;
                    flagI = 2;
                }
            }

            if(flagI == 0){
                System.out.println("Invalid entry, must be one of Y,y,N,n");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        while(flagA == 0){

            System.out.println("Does this session require authentication? Y/N");
            System.out.println();
            s = reader.next();
            System.out.println();

            if(s.equals("Y") || s.equals("y") || s.equals("N") || s.equals("n")){

                if(s.equals("Y") || s.equals("y")){
                    securityArray[2] = 1;
                    flagA = 1;
                }else{
                    securityArray[2] = 0;
                    flagA = 2;
                }
            }

            if(flagA == 0){
                System.out.println("Invalid entry, must be one of Y,y,N,n");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        //create security string

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            securityArrayString = securityArrayString + String.valueOf(securityArray[i]);
        }

        //Use security array values to create key, etc based on need

        if(securityArray[0] == 1){
            System.out.println("C operations needed");
        }

        if(securityArray[1] == 1){
            System.out.println("I operations needed");
        }

        if(securityArray[2] == 1){
            System.out.println("A operations needed");
        }       

        return securityArrayString;
    }







}
```

Comment: Which line throws the exception?  The key generator or the cipher?  Try giving a full algorithm identifier to the cipher e.g. "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding".  Also you're currently using ECB mode which makes your code insecure.

Comment: The key generator is the one throwing the error, I'll give the full identifier a shot

Comment: Does the cipher throw an exception if you comment out the key generator?  You could always generate the key manually.

Comment: No luck, changed the algorithm string to your suggestion and got the same results

Comment: @LukePark yes, if I comment out the key generator the cipher still throws the same exception

Comment: What JRE version/platform?

Comment: Please edit your question, including the full stacktrace of the exception and indicating which line of code causes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cipher's and KeyGenerator's getInstance() need different inputs:

```
key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey();
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```